# Where to put log_format clause what is its syntax?

Tags: nginx

Is /etc/nginx.conf the correct place to add a modified `log_format` clause?

I added the following just above `access_log` in /etc/nginx.conf:

```
log_format test '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
           '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
           '"$request_uri" "$http_user_agent" ! "$server_name"';
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
```

`nginx -t` says all ok, and I restarted nginx. However, access.log still shows the original output columns. I purposely place that `!` to see the impact of the change but the exclamation mark doesn't show up in the log.

What could be wrong? Is the syntax of my `log_format` statement correct?

`$request_uri` and `$server_name` are additional items I added to investigate a site configuration problem. I don't know if they are valid variables that can be used in `log_format`. Just trying my luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log test ;
```

For all options you can refer to this doc - [ngx_http_log_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)